# Expand LVM Logical Volume on Virtual Machine

Tags: lvm

I had a very specific problem. I have a LVM running on a single physical volume on a Virtual Machine. The size of the logical volume is ~150GB and I wish to expand it to ~250GB.

I was able to expand the physical volume from my Virtual Machine manager, but the change in physical size is not reflected on my LVM logical volume.

I didn't find any answers directly, and through some experimentation found a solution. I thought I'll share it in my answer below.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Thank you for taking the time to write such a high quality post! Though I will mention, AU is a Q&A site and not a forum, so I might suggest stating the issue you had in your question, and moving to solution into an answer. (You can answer your own question)

Comment: Thanks @AndroidDev I have moved my answer to the answer section

Comment: Please be sure to mark it as accepted :)

Comment: @AndroidDev thank you! I'll have to wait for 2 days apparently. So I will do that then.

Answer (score 9):

An example LVM diagram:

[image]

The idea of LVM is it abstracts the logical volume away from the physical volume, such that multiple physical volumes will appear to the user a single continuous logical volume.

The root file system is in `/dev/file-server-vg/root` and the swap is in `/dev/file-server-vg/swap`. The idea is we can actually have multiple real hard disks in the PV layer, and they can be all added into a Volume Group, which will allow them to all appear as a single continuous file system to the system at `/dev/file-server-vg/root`.

In this problem I have been using `/dev/file-server-vg/root` as a file server and it is running out of space. Luckily this system is on a virtual machine, and I was able to expand the physical volume `/dev/sda` using the virtual machine manager. However, the increase in size doesn’t get automatically passed to the `/dev/file-server-vg/root` file system. We need to do a few simple command to get this to work.

Before we start, use `pvdisplay` to see which physical volumes are present. This will list all the physical volumes and the volume group that it belongs to. In this case we only have one physical volume that is `/dev/sda3`.

```
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda3
  VG Name               file-server-vg
  PV Size               155.26 GiB / not usable 0   
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              65346
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          65346
  PV UUID               0EXhc4-EoHZ-b79R-ncSe-SWXI-ztPe-Fsc7zk
```

The current partition table can be listed by using `sudo parted` and then `print`.

```
Number  Start   End    Size   File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB  537MB  fat32              boot
 2      538MB   794MB  256MB  ext2
 3      794MB   167GB  166GB                     lvm
```

In this example we want to expand the capacity from 155.56GiB to 255.56GiB. Using the virtual machine manager we can usually extend the disk space, and in this case we will expand it by 100GiB.

After expansion is successful, the resulting partition table (use `print free`) will look like the following. Please note the “Free space” shows 108GB (~100GiB).

```
Number  Start   End    Size   File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB  537MB  fat32              boot
 2      538MB   794MB  256MB  ext2
 3      794MB   275GB  166GB                     lvm
      167GB   275GB  108GB  Free Space
```

There are two way to expand the logical volume: 
Create a new partition and add this to the Volume Group, or
Increase the same partition.

In my opinion, where possible, the second method is neater. Of course if `/dev/sda3` is a physical hard disk, and you bought another hard disk to expand the space, then it will be logical to use the first method.

In parted type `resize 3 794MB 275GB` will resize partition 3 to take up all the free space, well almost:

```
Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
        17.4kB  1049kB  1031kB  Free Space
 1      1049kB  538MB   537MB   fat32              boot
 2      538MB   794MB   256MB   ext2
 3      794MB   275GB   274GB                      lvm
        275GB   275GB   1032kB  Free Space
```

This is good enough, just 1MB not being used.

Next we will reboot the machine. This is needed to refresh the partition table.

What you will see now is that the physical volume has increased in size with `pvdisplay`

```
--- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda3
  VG Name               file-server-vg
  PV Size               255.26 GiB / not usable 0   
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              65346
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          65346
  PV UUID               0EXhc4-EoHZ-b79R-ncSe-SWXI-ztPe-Fsc7zk
```

This increase in size will be automatically passed to the volume group, using `vgdisplay` you get the following. Please note `vgextend` doesn’t actually do what you might think it does. It doesn’t take up the free space, instead it is used for adding new physical volumes to a particular volume group.

```
--- Volume group ---
  VG Name               file-server-vg
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  5
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                2
  Open LV               2
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               255.26 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              65346
  Alloc PE / Size       65346 / 255.26 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0   
  VG UUID               NwwIgT-W0SH-aeTe-d078-hcxx-XZ6W-QfnSA0
```

The logical volume doesn’t increase in size automatically. This is actually makes sense because the computer has no idea which logical volume you want to increase in size, or perhaps you want to create a new logical volume with the extra space in the volume group. So with `lvdisplay` you will see the following table, showing the `/dev/file-server-vg/root` only has 153.26GiB, but don’t worry we are very close.

```
--- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/file-server-vg/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                file-server-vg
  LV UUID                l6qvYZ-AmYw-tdgi-2jUu-XNB2-gecQ-6fDPt8
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time file-server, 2014-07-10 14:54:58 +1000
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                153.26 GiB
  Current LE             64834
  Segments               2
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:0

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/file-server-vg/swap_1
  LV Name                swap_1
  VG Name                file-server-vg
  LV UUID                OohMkN-rGLa-fM4M-6he2-MbM9-BBc3-Ck2Hs5
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time file-server, 2014-07-10 14:54:58 +1000
  LV Status              available
  # open                 2
  LV Size                2.00 GiB
  Current LE             512
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:1
```

The way to increase the logical volume is to use `lvextend -L +100GB /dev/file-server-vg/root`

After that expand the file system with `resize2fs /dev/file-server-vg/root`

And you are done. You can do `lvdisplay` to check that the `/dev/file-server-vg/root` volume has extended to 253.26GiB

```
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/file-server-vg/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                file-server-vg
  LV UUID                l6qvYZ-AmYw-tdgi-2jUu-XNB2-gecQ-6fDPt8
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time file-server, 2014-07-10 14:54:58 +1000
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                253.26 GiB
  Current LE             64834
  Segments               2
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:0

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/file-server-vg/swap_1
  LV Name                swap_1
  VG Name                file-server-vg
  LV UUID                OohMkN-rGLa-fM4M-6he2-MbM9-BBc3-Ck2Hs5
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time file-server, 2014-07-10 14:54:58 +1000
  LV Status              available
  # open                 2
  LV Size                2.00 GiB
  Current LE             512
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:1
```

Comment: Unfortunately this no longer works, because the `resize` command no longer exists in parted

Comment: @Cardin you can use `resizepart`

Comment: I used all of these commands outside parted. i.e. `pvdisplay` `lvdisplay` `lvextend -l+100%FREE /dev/file-server-vg/root` (slightly different from what is written in the answer, taken from: https://askubuntu.com/a/844478/176104) `resize2fs /dev/file-server-vg/root`. (All commands prefixed with sudo.) I also chose to run these commands from a gparted live cd boot, so that the partition was unmounted.

Comment: Thanks for a helpful answer :)